# Can the exit status message from SciPy Optimize be improved?

Tags: openmdao

In OpenMDAO v3.20.2, the optimization report was added ([here](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/reports/optimization_report.html#openmdao.visualization.opt_report.opt_report.opt_report)). I'm using the SciPyOptimizer SLSQP optimizer, and the report appears to have a bug. The iterations count from the report does not match the iteration count from the SciPy print statement (see below for direct readout). I think this issue could be addressed using the information found ([here](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Scipy/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html#scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult)) (e.g. in the scipy_optimizer.py file use `self.iter_count=result.nit`).

Also, the optimizer returns plenty of key optimization details that could be useful. For example, status indicates why the optimization failed/terminated (e.g. iteration limit, too many constraints, [etc](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Scipy/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp.html).). I think that information would be more useful than the current exit status which would just be `FAIL`.

Hopefully this is a useful suggestion.

```
Iteration limit reached    (Exit mode 9)
            Current function value: 1.5695626156067153
            Iterations: 20
            Function evaluations: 42
            Gradient evaluations: 16
Optimization FAILED.
Iteration limit reached
-----------------------------------
Time: 94.89042663574219

p.driver.opt_result['iter_count']
Out[2]: 43
```

Comment: This is not so much a question for SO, and more of a feature request. You're best off opening an issue on the openmdao github page, or potentially submitting a POEM (https://github.com/openmdao/poems) if you think its a large enough change

Comment: My apologies. Thanks for letting me know.